# Rewrite rule for social crawlers only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect facebook and twitter crawlers to some different page using following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot)
    RewriteRule ^/tags/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/statictag.php?id=$1
```

It is working but when I check my page domain.com/tags/abc on browser it is first **redirecting to base url and then showing me Page not found** error.

I am not able to understand why is it so?

Comment: The redirect is probably defined somewhere else in your configuration files.

Comment: @ortomala-lokni Other configuration files are default one. I have not changed other settings. And one more thing, without these rules my site is working correctly. I think something is wrong with this redirect only.